# updated input Values not refecting on child html component

Tags: lightning-web-components

On button click i am redirecting to child LWC by using **NavigationMixin.Navigate**.
Below is the URL which gets generated

```
https://XXXXXXXXX.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/c__ChildComp?c__recordId=1234555555&c__inputs=%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

c__inputs is a object which is coming from parent LWC like below -

```
          @track inputvalue = {
            name: "test",
            address:"test"
          };
handleClick() {
let name= this.template.querySelector(".name").value;
this.inputvalue.name= name;
}
```

and in navigation -

```
state: {
        c__recordId: this.recordId,
        c__inputs: this.inputvalue
      }
```

On child i am retriving the values as below -

```
     get recordIdFromState() {
        return (
          this.currentPageReference && this.currentPageReference.state.c__recordId
        );
      }

      get inputsFromState() {
        return (
          this.currentPageReference &&
          this.currentPageReference.state.c__inputs
        );
      }

  @track getName;
  @track recordId = "";

          renderedCallback() {
            this.recordId = this.recordIdFromState;
            this.getName = this.allinputsFromState;
            console.log(this.recordId);
          }
```

on Child HTML side i have the below -

**{getName.name}**

the issue which i am having is below -

1. after the redirect happens, if i just refresh the above url , the {getName.name} becomes blank.
2. after the redirect happens, if i go back to the parent page and fill the name field and hit click, the value is not changing on child. Its showing the previou old value.

Hope i am making sense.

Comment: c__inputs should not be an object, but JSON.

Comment: Sorry yes JSON.. in debug, it looks like "[object Object]"

Comment: `https://XXXXXXXXX.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/c__ChildComp?c__recordId=1234555555&c__inputs=%5Bobject%20Object%5D` says its object string and not JSON. URL cannot be binary and text only.

Comment: I have updated the code above, like how i am assigning values to c__inputs.

Comment: @learningmode If your `c__inputs` is a JSON, then that will not work. Any parameter that you pass using the `state` attribute has to be a String.

Comment: If i refresh the browser , it works fine, But if i just go to object tab without refreshing the browser and perform this action, its not working..

Comment: Can adding event might help?